# Google tag manager in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-tag-manager

I want to install in my site google tag manager. According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart):

i have to put this

```js
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

in the Head of the site, and this:

```js
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

in the body tag.

 Question: Who can explain why the script is wrapped in `nonscript` tag? Or in this case it won't be vissible for browsers where javascript is enabled. So, why should i add `nonscript`?

Answer (score 3):

The `<noscript>` variant lets you gather analytics via an iframe if the user has disabled javascript.

Since you're using React, unless you're using server-side rendering, your entire app will not work if the user has disabled javascript, so the `<noscript>` variant may not be useful to you at all and can be omitted.